# XSS Poor Validation Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, xss

I am getting XSS Poor Validation issue in the following code:

```
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 border=0 style="table-layout:fixed">
        <col width=20%>
        <col width=13%>
        <col width=20%>
        <col width=13%>
        <col width=20%>
        <col width=13%>
        <TR height=25>
            <TD class=border_title_sub colspan=2 align=center>미작성</TD>
            <TD class=border_title_sub colspan=2 align=center>임시저장중</TD>
            <TD class=border_title_sub colspan=2 align=center>작성완료</TD>
        </TR>
        <%
        do until (rs_1.EOF and rs_2.EOF and rs_3.EOF)
        %>
        <TR height=25>
            <%
            if rs_1.EOF then
            %>
                <TD class=border_text>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD class=border_text align=center>&nbsp;</TD>
            <%
            else
            rs_1_check_name  = rs_1("check_name")
            rs_1_user_name = rs_1("user_name")
            %>
                <TD class=border_text><%=HTMLDecode(Server.HTMLEncode(rs_1_check_name))%></TD>
                <TD class=border_text align=center><%=HTMLDecode(Server.HTMLEncode(rs_1_user_name))%></TD>
            <%
            end if

            if rs_2.EOF then
            %>
                <TD class=border_text>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD class=border_text align=center>&nbsp;</TD>
            <%
            else
            rs_2_check_name  = rs_2("check_name")
            rs_2_user_name = rs_2("user_name")
            %>
                <TD class=border_text><%=HTMLDecode(Server.HTMLEncode(rs_2_check_name))%></TD>
                <TD class=border_text align=center><%=HTMLDecode(Server.HTMLEncode(rs_2_user_name))%></TD>
            <%
            end if

            if rs_3.EOF then
            %>
                <TD class=border_text>&nbsp;</TD>
                <TD class=border_text align=center>&nbsp;</TD>
            <%
            else
            rs_3_check_name  = rs_3("check_name")
            rs_3_user_name = rs_3("user_name")
            %>
                <TD class=border_text><%=HTMLDecode(Server.HTMLEncode(rs_3_check_name))%></TD>
                <TD class=border_text align=center><%=HTMLDecode(Server.HTMLEncode(rs_3_user_name))%></TD>
            <%
            end if
            %>
        </TR>
        <%
        if not rs_1.EOF then rs_1.movenext
        if not rs_2.EOF then rs_2.movenext
        if not rs_3.EOF then rs_3.movenext
        loop
        rs_1.close
        rs_2.close
        rs_3.close
        set rs_1 = Nothing
        set rs_2 = Nothing
        set rs_3 = Nothing
        %>
    </TABLE>
```

Here, HTMLDecode is my custom function, which is defined as follows:

```
<%
Function HTMLDecode(sText)
    Dim I
    sText = Replace(sText, "&quot;", Chr(34))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))
    For I = 1 to 255
        sText = Replace(sText, "&#" & I & ";", Chr(I))
    Next
    HTMLDecode = sText
End Function
%>
```

As my data already encoded in the DB, I am using both Server.HTMLEncode("") [ To escape from Security SW ) and HTMLDecode("") [To display information properly].

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: issue in many lines. Sample lines are,                                           <TD class=border_text><%=HTMLDecode(Server.HTMLEncode(rs_1_check_name))%></TD>
                <TD class=border_text align=center><%=HTMLDecode(Server.HTMLEncode(rs_1_user_name))%></TD>

Comment: I have to ask - why have you got three different record sets open?

Comment: In theory you will get the exact same value after passing your value into both functions than if you just writed directly the recordset field value. Because HtmlEncode will replace "&nbsp;" with "&amp;nbsp;", so your HtmlDecode function will decode to "&nbsp;"

Comment: Yes. I know. But, how to escape from Security Scan Check. My data in DB is already encoded. If I display that directly, I am getting XSS : Consistent issue when it undergone Security Scan. If I use only, Server.HTMLEncode("") then, data is corrupted in display. So I am using both. Now, the security scan giving me XSS: Poor Validation issue.